# What exactly is Psycopg2?

Tags: postgresql, python

This question is for a report I'm writing for school. Technically speaking, what is Psycopg2? In [this tutorial](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial) they refer to it both as an "adapter" and "driver"

> Psycopg2 is a DB API 2.0 compliant PostgreSQL **driver** that is actively
>   developed. It is designed for multi-threaded applications and manages
>   its own connection pool. Other interesting features of the **adapter** are
>   that if you are using the PostgreSQL array data type, Psycopg will
>   automatically convert a result using that data type to a Python list.

Since it's `import`ed into Python, I would've guest it was a library?

What's the distinction between library, driver and adapter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`psycopg2` is a wrapper around [`libpq`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq.html), written in C, to expose a [Python DB-API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) compatible API to Python programs. It implements Python objects in C that call `libpq` functions. It has a thin Python module wrapper around it to load it and provide some of the interface functionality that's easier to write in pure Python.

Anything that implements the DB-API to connect to an external database can be reasonably called a *database driver* or *database adapter*. The two are pretty much interchangeable. Any DB-API implementation must be a Python module. Python modules are programming language libraries, in that they're collections of re-usable code. Some are also C shared libraries, in that they're compiled C code that gets linked into the cPython executable.