# How to see unclosed PostgreSQL connection while using psycopg2?

Tags: connections, python, postgresql-12

I run python code:

```
con = psycopg2.connect(some_dsn)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(some_sql)
res = cur.fetchone()
#con.close() <-- connection is not closed
```

Then I try:

```
ps auxf | grep postgres
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
```

both does not display correspond information.
How to see that unclosed connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Python answer

Given a `psycopg2` connection object called `conn`, initialized by, e.g.:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="my_database", 
                        user="username", 
                        password=password, 
                        host="localhost", 
                        port="5432")
```

If I'd like to see if `conn` is closed or not, what I usually do in [python 3](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/) is;

```
conn.closed
```

If the `.closed` method returns 1, then the connection is closed.
If the `.closed` method returns 0, then the connection is still opened.

As stated in the documentation:

> **closed**
>
> Read-only integer attribute: 0 if the connection is open, nonzero if
>   it is closed or broken.

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html

You can also see that by just typing in the name of your connection in a python console and watch at the `closed` key at the very end;

```
conn
Out[4]: <connection object at 0x7fe3d042e2b8; dsn: 'user=postgres 
        password=xxx dbname=my_database host=localhost port=5432', closed: 0>

conn.close()

conn
Out[6]: <connection object at 0x7fe3d042e2b8; dsn: 'user=postgres 
        password=xxx dbname=my_database host=localhost port=5432', closed: 1>
```

You can have more help on the connector methods by using:

```
help(conn)
```

### Notice

It's really important to close a connection once you are done with your changes. Do not forget to `commit()` them before, of course, otherwise your changes would be lost as if you performed a rollback as stated in the documentation of psycopg2:

> **close()**
>
> Close the connection now (rather than whenever del is executed). The
>   connection will be unusable from this point forward; an InterfaceError
>   will be raised if any operation is attempted with the connection. The
>   same applies to all cursor objects trying to use the connection. Note
>   that closing a connection without committing the changes first will
>   cause any pending change to be discarded as if a ROLLBACK was
>   performed (unless a different isolation level has been selected: see
>   set_isolation_level()).

Source: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html

## psql and system tools answer

From `psql`, you can also list connections.

For example by using this command:

```
select pid as process_id, 
       usename as username, 
       datname as database_name, 
       client_addr as client_address, 
       client_hostname,
       client_port,
       application_name,
       backend_start,
       state,
       state_change
from pg_stat_activity;
```

or as you simply stated `select * from pg_stat_activity;`.
The interesting thing to notice here is the value of `client_port`.

The former command being modified after: https://dataedo.com/kb/query/postgresql/list-database-sessions

In any cases, the question and answer given here:    [What exactly is Psycopg2?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111969/what-exactly-is-psycopg2)
may be helping understanding that it's barely impossible to differentiate a `psycopg2` connection from a standard connection from outside Python using `psql`; a connection open with `psycopg2` will look like any other opened connections.

But...

Now, if you open a `psycopg2` connection and you carefully watch at the output of the aforementioned `psql` command, you will of course see an extra line while the connection is opened (compared to a closed `psycopg2` connection).
In an example on my system, the line which corresponds to the connection open by `psycogp2` looks like:

```
 process_id | username | database_name | client_address | client_hostname | client_port |     application_name     |         backend_start         | state  |         state_change          
------------+----------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------
      12693 | postgres | my_database   | 127.0.0.1      |                 |       59218 |                          | 2020-03-22 10:58:12.143291+01 | idle   | 2020-03-22 10:58:12.149866+01
```

It opened a connection on `client_port` `59218`.
As I said, from here, you cannot differentiate from any other connections.

Then, if I look at the output of `ps -ef | grep "PID\|59218"` (`59218` being the `client_port` of the previous `psql` output) I have:

```
$ ps -ef | grep "PID\|59218"
```

UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
postgres 14663 31224  0 10:59 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 10/main: postgres my_database 127.0.0.1(59218) idle

Again, this looks exactly the same as any other connection, so I cannot know which application has opened this connection.

But you can further explore the outputs of [`netstat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/netstat.8.html):

```
$ sudo netstat -ap | grep -i "Proto\|59218"
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 localhost:59218         localhost:postgresql    ESTABLISHED 859/python3         
tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    localhost:59218         ESTABLISHED 14663/postgres: 10/ 
(...)
```

Where `localhost:postgresql` corresponds to `localhost:5432` (this can be seen by activating/deactivating the `-P` flag of `lsof`.) Here you can also see the same `postgres` `PID` as the one in the `ps` output above.
So `postgresql` is ready to accept IO operations with `python3` on the client port `59218` which was opened. This port closes when the `psycopg2` connection is closed.

So you can try to figure out that `client_port` for the connection between `python3` and `postgresql`, e.g. by:

```
sudo netstat -ap | grep -i "python3" | grep "postgres"
```

and then [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) for its value in the output of either `psql` and `ps`.

### Notice

I also tried to use the `sockstat` tool:

```
$ sudo sockstat | grep -i "PID\|5432\|59218"
USER     PROCESS              PID      PROTO  SOURCE ADDRESS            FOREIGN ADDRESS           STATE
username python3              859      tcp4   127.0.0.1:59136           127.0.0.1:5432            ESTABLISHED
postgres postgres             14663    tcp4   127.0.0.1:5376            127.0.0.1:59218           ESTABLISHED
```

Here, I unfortunately don't know what is this `59136` port used by Python itself in the source address, nor the `5376` port used by postgres as both doesn't match the default port specified by my `pscopg2` connection which is `5432`.
There is probably underlying protocols/connections being used in socket connections and I'm not an expert in networking to explain those.

I also found this thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/128284/how-to-see-active-connections-and-current-activity-in-postgresql-8-4

It also mentions an interesting tool called [pg_top`](https://pg_top.gitlab.io/) but which doesn't completely answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for exhaustive answer, @s.k. I'm aware about `.closed`, it is useful method on python side. Сlarification: I expected to see bunch of rows in `pg_stat_activity` or `postgres` processes with some correspond state(`idle` for example).  Probably I dont understand nature of database connection.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. So, short; you can try to use `netstat` and `grep` both on `pythonX` and `postgres` to see the active connection between these two processes. Details in the updated answer. This would obviously need further investigations, especially if many connections are open from Python side. Hope it helps.